# JQuery wait message dialogue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin which works like the `Ext.MessageBox.show(config)` with the `wait` property set as true. It should be a modal dialog with a message and progressbar.

I've done some search on this and found some widgets like

- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/)
- [imProgressBar](http://grasshopperpebbles.com/demos/index.php/progressbar/popup)
- [Matt Berseth's](http://mattberseth2.com/demo/Default.aspx?Name=jQuery.UI+ProgressBar+Widget&Filter=All)

but none of them provides the functionality like the `Ext.MessageBox`, Is there any other better plugin to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue by writing my own widget using [JQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).